# iphone - transforming a view-based project

Tags: iphone

sorry bothering you guys with this silly question, but I am a kind of noob in iphone development. What I need to do is this. I have a project developed by a friend of mine, that is view-based. He created it based on the original apple template on Xcode.

After banging my head on the wall, I realized that I need to transform this project from view based to UINavigation based project. What I mean is: his project has one view controller and one delegate. When it runs, the delegate calls the view controler and the equivalent view loads.

What I need is to insert a UINavigationController before the ViewController, because I am planning to have a second ViewController managed by this UINavigationController, so I can do slide transitions between them and things like that.

My question is: I imagine this is not a complex operation if you want where to change. Which changes and where should I do them, in order to add a UINavigationController before the viewController? I imagine this will change the hierarchy to:

Delegate > UINavigagionController > ViewController

Remember that this project was based on the Xcode View-based template, so I will probably have to change stuff on Interface Builder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In IB, add a `UINavigationController` to your MainWindow.xib.
- Drag the existing view controller onto the nav controller icon to make it the nav controller's root controller.
- In your code, add a property to your application delegate for the navigation controller. Mark it as `IBOutlet`.
- In IB, connect the navigation controller object to the navigation controller outlet in your app delegate.
- In your code, in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, change the references to your original view controller to the new navigation controller property.

Comment: Thanks. When I add the navigationcontroller on the MainWindow.xib it contains a viewController there, called Root View Controller. When I try to drag the existing viewController on the NC, it puts it inside this Root View Controller. It this correct?

Comment: No, you must replace the root controller with your view controller.